# how to post JSON ARRAY data to server in Android

Tags: android, json, getjson

I want to send below JSON data to server and read the response in android.
Below is the Json data.

```
{
    "class": "OrderItemListDto",
    "orderItemList": [
        {
            "class": "OrderItemDto",
            "orderId": 24,
            "itemId": 1,
            "quantity": 2,
            "status": "NEW",
            "sRequest": "none"
        },
        {
            "class": "OrderItemDto",
            "orderId": 24,
            "itemId": 2,
            "quantity": 2,
            "status": "NEW",
            "sRequest": "none"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here May be data will be increased.

Comment: Magic? If that isn't an option, please post what you have so far and *exactly what* you are stuck on.

Comment: please use search first. For example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316501/sending-json-object-using-post-methods

Comment: Thanks, Now I send JSONObject data to server successfully because my data was like {"class":"OrderItemDto","orderId":24,"itemId":1}.But now I have to send multiple data that i.e JSONArray data like above at the question.So how I will send data and get response.

Comment: How about searching out and trying out yourself first?

Answer (score 7):

Check this code

```
JSONArray json = //your array;
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpContext httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://your_url");

try {

    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());

    httpPost.setEntity(se);
    httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");


    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, httpContext); //execute your request and parse response
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    String jsonString = EntityUtils.toString(entity); //if response in JSON format

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Android doesn't have special code for sending and receiving HTTP, you can use standard Java code. I'd recommend using the Apache HTTP client, which comes with Android. Here's a snippet of code I used to send an HTTP POST.

```
try {   int TIMEOUT_MILLISEC = 10000;  // = 10 seconds
        HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
        HttpClient client =new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);   
        HttpPost request =new HttpPost("");
        request.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(postMessage.toString().getBytes("UTF8")));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        }catch (Exception e) {        
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also send Json in string form to server using WebClient class.

```
WebClient webClient; 
        //show progress dialog
        Uri uriImageUploadURL = new Uri ( "ServerStringUploadUri" );
        webClient = webClient ?? new WebClient ();
        webClient.Headers.Add ( "Content-Type" , "text/json" );
        webClient.UploadStringAsync ( uriImageUploadURL , "POST" , "JsonStringToUpload" );
        webClient.UploadStringCompleted += StringUploadCompleted;
```